# SQL - Finding the ID of each value before inserting it

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `os` which is holding the OS of mobiles phones. Attributes are `os_id` and `name`. `os_id` will be used from another table called `device`. As far I know each time I will insert a new record in device I need to `SELECT` from `os` the `os_id` that it's `name` is the same with the one that the user sends. That will happen for all the informations that are using `ids`(not only for `os`). Is there any better solution to avoid using `SELECT` 3-4 times per insertion?

NOTE:
 This is not HTML project. It's a web service and data will be pushed as string from the mobile device

Comment: How the user will select/enter these values like OS of device, using dropdown lists?

Comment: have you ever tried SCOPE_IDENTITY()   ?

Comment: @saurav Will be web services and it will be pushed as string from the mobile device.

Comment: Try merging Insert and Select queries, for example, INSERT INTO device(os_id) VALUES SELECT os_id FROM os WHERE name = $input_name;
(In some cases you cant trust user input, You should validate data server side)

Comment: @BlackM Then there must be another webservice that will return list of OS names to the mobile app, now you should send os_id along with names in that web service. The person who is working on mobile application code will show OS name to the user but he will send os_id of the selected OS name to your web service.

Comment: I know that approach (merging) but the problem is that I have to "SELECT" about 3-4 times per insertion and that's what I want to avoid.

Comment: Can you implement a mapping logic into the web service? E.g.  You could cache the "device" table and to the mapping between names and ids at an application layer.

Comment: Unfortunately is an automatic request on the mobile app startup. So there is no user interaction. I could a hardcoded mapping but I don't like that approach.

Comment: In such case, I will suggest that don't create separate tables for those values like OS name etc. and store these values in device table's columns. This way you can reduce many read-write operations. But, it depends on other requirements of your application.

Comment: Don't be afraid oft the extra selects. Put them into the insert clause as suggested by Abhishek Sharma. Add an index to the OS table over both name and os_id (a covering index for the lookup), or make os_id the primary unique key of an `WITHOU OID` table and add an index over name alone. In both cases, as long as the number of OSs is small, you will get away with a single disk access which will most likely be in the cache anyway. While the lookup in the database of course adds overhead, it is needed to comply with requirements. Adding the translation outside of the DB code will have...

Comment: ... similar overhead. If performance is a severe issue, prepare the insert statement and reuse it for multiple requests. You might want prepared statements as a defense against injection as well.

Answer (score 0):

Best approach is to receive `os_id` from front end user not `os_name`. I don't know what you are using in UI to do this but I am suggesting to use dropdown populated by `os_id` as value and `os_name` as text. While user selects `os_name`, respective `os_id` will be submitted with request.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I wasn't clear enough that this will be  a webservice and the os name will be pushed by mobile automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can just get os_id from user.

```
<select name="os">
    <option value="os_id">name</option>
</select>
```

Don't forget create relationships between tables! In this case INSERT command will return error if os_id from user does't exist in os table.